# Prove that $f$ is injective on $A$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $A=\{(x,y):x+y\neq -1\}$.Define $f:A\to \Bbb R^2$ by $f(x,y)=(\dfrac{x}{1+x+y},\dfrac{y}{1+x+y})$. Then which are true:

1.The Jacobian matrix of $f$ does not vanish on $A$.

2.$f$ is infinitely differentiable on $A$.

3.$f$ is injective on $A$.

4.$f(A)=\Bbb R^2$.

$f_1=\dfrac{x}{1+x+y},f_2=\dfrac{y}{1+x+y}.$
Then $\dfrac{\partial  f_1}{\partial x}=\dfrac{1+y}{(1+x+y)^2};\dfrac{\partial  f_1}{\partial y}=\dfrac{-1}{(1+x+y)^2};$

$\dfrac{\partial  f_2}{\partial x}=\dfrac{-1}{(1+x+y)^2}$;$\dfrac{\partial  f_1}{\partial y}=\dfrac{1+x}{(1+x+y)^2}$

which are non-zero on $A$. Hence 1 is true.

How to check 2?

For 3 If we suppose that $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$ I am getting that $x_1-x_2=x_1y_2-x_2y_1=y_2-y_1$
From here how to conclude $(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$?

I can't solve 4 also.

Comment: In the definition of $A$, $x+y\ne 1$? or $x+y\ne -1$.

Comment: I second that because otherwise it's impossible to have it being injective.

Comment: Your function isn't even defined on that region, since it has a division by 0 on the line $x+y=-1$

Comment: @BrianO;@Zelos;@Alan ;Please see the edits

Comment: What is yoyr definition of differentiability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (2), simply note that if for some function $g, g(x, y) = \frac{P(x,y)}{(1+x+y)^n}$ for some polynomial $P$ and natural number $n$, then $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{Q(x,y)}{(1+x+y)^k}$$ for some other polynomial $Q$ and some other natural number $k$ (which could potentially be less than $2n$ because of cancellation). And the same is true for the partial derivative with respect to $y$.

For (3), you can make use of theorems about the Jacobian, although the disconnected domain makes that is a little more difficult, as you have to manually show that the images of the two components don't overlap. But a much simpler approach works fine: calculate the inverse of $f$ directly! Note that if $f(x, y) = (u, v)$, then $$u + v = \frac{x + y}{1 + x + y} = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + x + y}$$ I'll leave the rest to you.

(4) The inverse function from (3) should make the answer to this one obvious.

Comment: Seriously i can't get how to show that $f$ is injective from $u+v=\frac{x+y}{1+x+y}$

Comment: Can you give some more details what you intend to say about that though not a full solution

Comment: Solve $u + v = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + x + y}$ for $1 + x + y$. Now since $u = \frac x {1 + x + y}$ and $v = \frac y {1 + x + y}$, can you see to express $x$ and $y$ as functions of $u$ and $v$? That is the inverse.

Comment: but the answer is 4 is false

Comment: That's right. Look at the inverse. does it exist for EVERY value of $f(x,y ) = (u, v)$? No. It doesn't work when $1 - u - v = 0$. That means there are some values in $\Bbb R^2$ that cannot be inverted. It is easy to see that this is because they can never be taken on by $f$ in the first place. The image of $f$ is not all of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Yes ,you are right it is not surjective as $x=\dfrac{u}{1-v-u};y=\dfrac{v}{1-v-u}$ ;but sir I am still not getting how you are concluding that it is injective from this representation of $x,y$

Comment: Inverse $\implies$ injective: if $f(x_1, y_1) = f(x_2, y_2)$ then $$(x_1, y_1) = f^{-1}\circ f(x_1,y_1) = f^{-1}\circ f(x_2,y_2) = (x_2, y_2)$$